# CSV - need comma at the start when first field is not present - csv generated from excel

Tags: excel, csv

I am using excel to generate comma separated values. I have a parser to parse the csv data and insert to database. 
The issue I face is, the first field in my csv is not mandatory. When the first field is null, the generated csv has no comma BEFORE the second field and for the parser the second field becomes the first field.

When the first field is null, I expect the data to be like below.

```
,SECOND_FIELD, THIRD_FIELD
```

I have tried

1. putting a space in the first field. In this case I wil have to change my parser.
2. Putting a static header. Then the comma is coming as expected in the underlying rows when first field is null. Change in parser will be required.
3. Putting a comma in the first field, but this is put as ",". :-)

Can someone through some solutions or workarounds ?

Thanks

Comment: When I save a sheet as .CSV I do get a comma when the first cell is empty. Maybe it depends on the version of Excel. I'm using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround: Why don't you check how many values are present? If one is missing, asume it's the first one.

**EDIT:**
I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529123/how-not-to-skip-empty-first-cell-when-saving-as-csv) that may help you. In a nutshell: apply any formatting to the range of cells you are using so Excel doesn't skip any of them when exporting. Also, I think that if you can swap the first column (optional) with any other one (required), it will work, too.

Comment: there are multiple fields first field is optional, 2, 3, 4 mandatory and again 5, 6, 7 optional. So I cannot count the number of fields and decide. I could not hold the issue for long and hence as a work around, I changed my parser and made like below
mandatory, optional, mandator, mandatory, optional, optional, optional