# Eliminate Blank Rows and Columns When Creating .CSV File with VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, csv

I am trying to output file to use in python as csv.

However, when I run my VBA macro, csv file that saved contain commas for blank rows and columns. Becaue of that I can not use the file in python to read and to do other works.

That I used save as csv file script here:

```
Sub FromExcelToNpad()

For m = 1 To 24
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ColumnOpenSeesInput-0- I").Cells(1, m) = i
    i = i + 1
Next m

    Dim myCSVFileName As String
    Dim tempWB As Workbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo err

    myCSVFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Column_0_I.csv"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ColumnOpenSeesInput-0- I").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook

    With tempWB
    .SaveAs Filename:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close
    End With
err:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

When I run it, my output file looks like;

[image]

How can I eliminate blank rows & columns I did not find good way. I just want to save useful cells with this way.

Comment: what did you find in official documentation for `SaveAs` ?

Comment: using Google `vba excel saveas skip empty cells` I found [how not to skip empty first cell when saving as .CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529123/how-not-to-skip-empty-first-cell-when-saving-as-csv)

Comment: try using pandas package to read your csv into a dataframe

Comment: @tudopropaganda Actually I use pandas to read csv file in python however VBA' output coming out with empty cells as you can see, in picture that I shared above.

Comment: @furas I have some inputs with other variables that come from in excel calculations. Then I prepare all inputs to use in python as csv format. However, vba is not working what I think like that. I did not find correct command to delete empty cells before the saving. also I will check link that you mentioned! thanks!

Comment: I don't know VBA (and I don't use Windows to use VBA)  but if you can't delete it in VBA then maybe load it with Python and delete it in Python - It should be simply to recognize empty rows and columns and delete them in `pandas`

Comment: This might be a problem with what Excel see's as the used range. You could try resetting that by simply adding  `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` to the code before you save the file.

Comment: Excel has very fixed ideas on what a CSV file should look like.  When you want something different to that, it's best to write your own CSV handler.  [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674433) you can adapt to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Windows so I can't check how to do it in `VBA` but I would use `Python` and `pandas` to remove empty rows and columns.

```
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)  # remove rows with NaN in all cells
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)  # remove cols with NaN in all cells
```

---

Minimal working example.

I uses `io.StringIO` only to simulate file with data. You should test it with `filename`

```
text = '''A,B,C,,,,,,,,,,,
1,2,3,,,,,,,,,,,
4,5,6,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))
#df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)  # remove rows with NaN in all cells
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)  # remove cols with NaN in all cells

print( df )
```

Result:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  5.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
' deletes blank rows on the specified  worksheet.
' If the argument is omitted, ActiveSheet is processed
Public Sub DelEmptyRows(Optional ws As Worksheet = Nothing)
    Dim toDel As Range, rng As Range, r As Range
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.UsedRange)
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r) = 0 Then
            If toDel Is Nothing Then
                Set toDel = r
            Else
                Set toDel = Union(toDel, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not toDel Is Nothing Then toDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

' deletes blank columns on the specified  worksheet.
' If the argument is omitted, ActiveSheet is processed
Public Sub DelEmptyCols(Optional ws As Worksheet = Nothing)
    Dim toDel As Range, rng As Range, c As Range
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.UsedRange)
    For Each c In rng.Columns
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(c) = 0 Then
            If toDel Is Nothing Then
                Set toDel = c
            Else
                Set toDel = Union(toDel, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not toDel Is Nothing Then toDel.EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```